# JS Regex help needed to create CashTags

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

I have the following JS code (below) which takes a string and spits out hyperlinked cash tags (i.e. $AAPL $TSE:BB etc etc) ... it works great but the problem is if my text contained something like "$N225".. I still want that to be hyperlinked, but because it contains a number it doesn't work. But at the same time, I don't want it to hyperlink something like "$2.50" ... there needs to be a letter in front of it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
String.prototype.parseSymbols = function () {
    'use strict';
    return this.replace(/[$]+[A-Za-z]+/g, function (u) {
        var symbol = u.replace("$", "").toUpperCase();
        return u.link("/stocks/" + symbol);
    });
};
```

Comment: that doesn't work.. $2.50 doesn't link which is good.. but $n225 doesn't work and $TSE:BB doesn't work now either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You want your RegExp to say "A dollar sign, followed by any letter, followed by any number of letters or numbers, optionally followed by a colon and more letters/numbers. Ergo: `/\$[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(:[A-Z0-9]+)?/ig`.

```js
function parseSymbols(str) {
  return str.replace(/\$[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(:[A-Z0-9]+)?/ig, function (u) {
      var symbol = u.replace("$", "").toUpperCase();
      return u.link("/stocks/" + symbol);
  });
};

console.log(parseSymbols('a $N225 b $2.25 c $TSE:BB d $TSE:B:::B: e $::'));
```

Comment: I don't have enough information. Should `$TSE:B:::B:` also work?

Comment: Instead of `A-Za-z` just use the `i` modifier! And instead of `0-9` use `\d`! That would be better!

Comment: This does the trick.. /[$]+[A-Za-z:][A-Za-z0-9:]+/g  ... thanks all

Comment: @MrJones could it start with `:`? And have multiple of them?

Comment: @MrJones I've updated my answer. Also, the RegExp in your comment, `/[$]+[A-Za-z:][A-Za-z0-9:]+/g`, *will* match strings like `$TSE:B:::B:` or even `$::`, but it *won't* match single-letter symbols like `$A`.